# Angular cli ng generate to specific format or customize the generated code

Tags: angular, angular-cli

We are now open sourcing our project and as the open source requirement each file in the project need to contain license comment in top of the file.

Once the user downloaded the code they can add more component, directive, pipes, etc in to the project. We want, when the user will run any `ng` command inside the project directory, the new created component, directive or pile will also generated with the license comment at the top of the file.

for example where a component generated it have the below code format

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-restaurant',
  templateUrl: './restaurant.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./restaurant.component.scss']
})
export class RestaurantComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I want it to be like this.

```
/*
* Copyright 2017 shepherd contributors
*
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
* You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
*     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
*/
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-restaurant',
  templateUrl: './restaurant.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./restaurant.component.scss']
})
export class RestaurantComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Is there a way we can achieve in current angular cli?

Comment: Why do you need this in your sources?

Comment: Just add some postprocessor and add some headers on build.

Comment: You'd have to fork the CLI, it's [not currently supported](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2377).

Comment: build will generate minified code to run on server, we are open sourcing it and we need it to be in the future component generated or created in our project using ng command

Comment: @jonrsharpe, is there any work around rather to fork the code and change it

Comment: I don't know how else to say it: *it's not currently supported*.

Comment: This just in ... it **IS** now supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to have custom templates was just added and is now available in beta: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2377#issuecomment-325910253

However, there are currently no docs so it may be a bit trial and error until the docs are available.